# mysql: correlated subqueries and/or left join

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

I'm very new to all this so I apologise in advance for such a basic question.

I have three tables: Problems, Solutions and Votes.

Problems has: ID, Problem

Solutions has: ID, ProblemID, Solution

Votes has: ID, SolutionID, Vote Type, Date/time

The plan is that any user can post a problem (for an internal work site) and anyone can add a list of solutions. They can then also vote on any solution for a given problem. They can also change their mind, choose a different solution allowing us to see how opinion has changed over time. VoteType will be recorded as Stick or Twist. Stick being their current vote, Twist being a record that they have changed their mind.

I am looking for a mysql query to output all of the Solutions to a given Problem with appropriate votes counted in the next column (all the sticks for now). The problem I am having is that I cannot work out how to use subqueries and left join correctly so that if a solution has no votes, i can still output "0" or "no votes" in the appropriate place.

Again, i'm very new to this so i apologise for such a stupid question! Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select p.Problem, s.Solution, count(v.ID) as Sticks
 from Problems as p 
 inner join Solutions as s on s.ProblemID = p.ProblemID 
 left outer join Votes as v on  v.SolutionID = s.SolutionID 
                            and v.VoteType = 'Stick' 
 group by s.ID
```

Comment: First question and an amazing answer! Thank you all so much!